# Inserting extra vertices / triangles to give the model more geometry

Tags: geometry

I have a lo poly model.

I would like to give it a bit more geometry here and there.

This is a screenshot of what I would like to achieve:

[image]

The left side shows the "original" object.
On the right side one can see how some extra vertices were inserted.

This was done in a different software.

How could this be done in Blender?

Thank you very much!

I'm using Blender 2.81.

Comment: You can subdivide (W->S) Triangulate (Ctrl+T) or poke (Alt+P) the faces. And check out these menus: Ctrl+F Ctrl+E Ctrl+V (faces, edges, verts), may be you will find some useful tool.

Comment: @FFeller W->S does something different in Blender 2.8, I think?

Comment: @FFeller "W" brings up a circle, and "S" scales the face.

Comment: W calls up the Face Context Menu for me, if you want to find it in the Preferences. You can also use the search function in the 3D view. Subdivision also located in the CTRL+E (edge) menu.

Comment: Thanks. I have added my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, I have to select the faces in question.
To do that, select the face selection.

Select all your faces by using Shift.

Then, click the "Edge" menu, then click "Subdivide" to subdivide all selected faces.

[image]